# fetch_object() working once, then returning "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, mysql

I've read through many of the fetch_object() posts on this site, and non of them have any reference to the problem I have been having.

I am running the code:

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE ID = {$n}");
$name = $sql->fetch_object()->name;
$itemfunction = $sql->fetch_object()->itemfunction; //issue here
echo "<div id='" . $n . "' class='item " . $itemfunction . "'><p>";
echo $name . "<br>";
echo $count . "x";
echo "</p></div>";
```

`$n` is defined earlier, it is 1 in the case I am having issues with.

`$name` is defined appropriately, and the `echo $name` line works as it should, but the `$itemfunction` line returns the error:

"Trying to get property of non-object"

The second, third, and fourth `echo` lines run appropriately, the first runs correctly other than the `$itemfunction` returning nothing.

Both 'name' and 'itemfunction' are type: 'varchar(60)' and collation: 'utf8_general_ci' in the mysql table.

'name' has the value 'Leather Cap' and 'itemfunction' has the value 'equip'

Is there any reason why `fetch_object()` wouldn't work twice?

Comment: _“Is there any reason why fetch_object() wouldn't work twice?”_ – because you have only _one_ result record …?

Comment: If I understood what that meant, I wouldn't be having a problem. @Muhammet answered it and actually explained why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result sets works with cursors, when you use `fetch_object()` the pointer moves on, so it is `NULL` when calling it second time.

Instead just save the result in a variable:

```
$data = $sql->fetch_object()->name;
$name = $data->name;
$itemfunction = $data->itemfunction;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I changed the code to run the query twice and it returns properly now.

Comment: You should not run the query twice.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call fetch_object, you advance the pointer. A better way to manage many rows (or even one, in your case) would be with a loop:

```
while ($obj = $sql->fetch_object()) {
    $name = $obj->name;
    $itemfunction = $obj->itemfunction;
    //Do other work here, or just append those to an array.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. There are multiple rows, the above code fits into a large while statement, I just simplified it to narrow down on the problem.